# What is the difference between using a class and not using a class in Python

Tags: python

So I'm working on a personal Python project as of right now and I would research a certain question I had. However, lots of the code samples looked like this:

```
x = 0
class foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        global x
        x += 1
        self.y = x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    newClass = foo()
    newClass.bar()
    print(newClass.y)
```

Just a loose example.
Is there any advantage of doing that over this:

```
x = 0
y = 0
def bar():
    global x
    global y
    x += 1
    y = x
bar()
print(y)
```

Is the class quicker and more efficient or is it just a matter of personal preference? I tend to use the one shown above, without the class, but should I use the class instead?

Comment: Documentation can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/419/classes#t=201608261803105160761

Comment: The Pythonic answer is use whatever makes sense.  If you aren't using anything that a class gives you, don't use a class.  If using a class makes it easier to understand your code, use a class.

Comment: You can't make two "instances" of `bar`, so I'm not sure if you can meaningfully compare them.

Comment: http://kentsjohnson.com/stories/00014.html A useful post from 2004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is your design, how your code can be used, how it can be extended, and how you can manage it.

Your example is so short that you don't even need functions let alone classes.  But that is an artifact of such a short example.

In your example, `self.y` will be different for each instance of the class `foo` that you create.  When you declare `y` to be a global, then you have only one of them for your entire program.

Try adding this to your example and see if you understand the results.

```
first = foo()
second = foo()

first.bar()
print(first.y)

first.bar()
print(first.y)

second.bar()
print(first.y)
print(second.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there is no advantage to using classes for small programs. There is, however, a huge advantage to using classes for large programs, and you should think of small programs as practice for writing large programs.